# Swift dynamic properties in initialization

Tags: swift, class, initialization, swift-playground

I am working in Xcode 7 beta 5 with Swift 2.0.  I think I am having an issue with initialization of a struct.

```
enum Resource {
    case gold
    case elixer
    case darkElixer
}

class Avatar {
    let cost, health, damage, space: Int
    let lifeSpan: Double
    let costType: Resource


    init(damage: Int, health: Int, cost: Int, costType: Resource, space: Int){
        self.damage = damage
        self.health = health
        self.cost = cost
        self.costType = costType
        self.space = space
        self.lifeSpan = Double(damage / health)
}
```

I am having trouble with the line.

```
self.lifeSpan = Double(damage / health)
```

I'm just trying to figure out how to dynamically set properties during initialization.

Comment: Do you want lifespan to always be equal to `damage / health`? Use a method then.

Comment: A computed property would probably be better — but since these are `let` constants, the initially calculated value will always be correct.

Comment: What I was looking for was a computed property. Thank you @jtbandes

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found the answer to be.

```
var lifeSpan: Double {
    get {
        return  Double(health) / Double(damage)
    }

}
```

Comment: Fun fact: the `get` part is actually unneeded, if it's the only section :)

Comment: @jtbandes I like having the "get" I think it adds readability.